# IE-8 stopped working with error code c0000005

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a web application that simply uses :
1. Spring 
2. Hibernate 
3. Ajax
4. Jquery
5. Html
6. Css
When I click on a link(on a page in my application) microsoft error appears on a pop-up (Internet explorer has stopped responding)
Details given in error is:

```
Problem Event Name:        APPCRASH
 Application Name:        iexplore.exe
 Application Version:        8.0.7601.17514
 Application Timestamp:        4ce79912
 Fault Module Name:        mshtml.dll
 Fault Module Version:        8.0.7601.17514
 Fault Module Timestamp:        4ce7b8f3
 Exception Code:        c0000005
 Exception Offset:        000cb20b
 OS Version:        6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
 Locale ID:        1033
 Additional Information 1:        0a9e
 Additional Information 2:        0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
 Additional Information 3:        0a9e
 Additional Information 4:        0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
 C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

That link or page is working on all other browsers including IE-9 and 10 too.
I have tried resetting the IE configuration, forced re-install IE-8 but nothing works.
My key dependency is on IE-8 , please provide me solution of this ridiculous problem.
Thanks In adavnce.

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is you've found something that crashes IE8. You know that already of course but my point is that you haven't given us enough info to help you find the issue. Suggestions: 1) [google the error](0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789 iexplore.exe). 2) Virus scan your IE8 machine. 3) Check to see if other pages/sites also act the same way on this machine. 4) Try to cut down your code to remove elements from the equation; eg save the raw HTML code and test that to eliminate Spring/Hibernate; reduce the size of the code to get the smallest example that repoduces the issue.

Comment: Actually the abstract info about this problem is only the reason that I am totally unaware what extra I will post here that will provide you a brief picture about this. Simply clicking on link this happens without any error. And hard time for me as my customers are totally dependent on IE-8 :( :'(

Comment: did you try my suggestions? [googling the error](http://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr#q=iexplore.exe+0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789) might give you some clues about other people who have had the same problem. And reducing the code to the minimum required to cause the crash will definitely be helpful.

Comment: Tried every solution as stated by you...instead I have emptied the code from my JSP page (only the existence of that link), still this error resides. :( :'(...still googling all are providing the same solution as stated by you....and even I resetted all properties of IE, re-installed it, but no success :(